# Adding custom properties to Ember Model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to add a custom property to an Ember Data Model. Specifically I want to add a property which defines the REST end point to use in an Ember Data Adapter I'm writing.

My Model is defined as such (with custom property 'endPoint'):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({

partner_id      : DS.attr('string'),
partner_key     : DS.attr('string'),
partner_name    : DS.attr('string'),
created         : DS.attr('string'),
status          : DS.attr('string'),
type            : DS.attr('string'),

endPoint        : 'api_entry'
```

});

In my Adapter I'm trying to access the property as follows:

```
_buildURL: function (modelName, store, id, snapshot, requestType, query) {

    var host, namespace, url;

    var model = store.modelFor(modelName);

    var endPoint = model.endPoint;
    var endPoint2 = Ember.get(model, 'endPoint');

    console.log(endPoint, endPoint2);

    host = Ember.get(this, "host");
    namespace = Ember.get(this, "namespace");

    url = [];

    if (host) {
        url.push(host);
    }

    if (namespace) {
        url.push(namespace);
    }

    url.push(modelName);

    url = url.join("/");

    if (!host) {
    url = "/" + url;
    }

    return url;
},
```

In the console.log above, both endPoint and endPoint2 are undefined. I'm new to Ember and Javascript. What am I doing wrong? Is there a more 'Ember' way to do this? I don't want to use the actual REST endpoint names as my model names as they do not adhere to Ember model naming conventions.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `buildURL` function dealing with the model *class* as opposed to the model *instance*. You need to add the property to the class:

```
var model = DS.Model.extend({
  partner_id      : DS.attr('string'),
  partner_key     : DS.attr('string'),
  partner_name    : DS.attr('string'),
  created         : DS.attr('string'),
  status          : DS.attr('string'),
  type            : DS.attr('string')
});

model.reopenClass({
  endPoint        : 'api_entry'
});

export default model;
```

Comment: This works but I'm not sure the model is the right place to put this. Better to use an adapter.

Comment: Then you need a special adapter for every model. This way you can write the code once in the application adapter

Comment: @dwickern - thanks so much for answering, saved me a lot of frustration! I guess I'm missing a fundamental concept here, let me explain. I can add custom properties to a controller that is derived via:

'export default Ember.Controller.extend'

So why can't I add them to a model that is also derived via "extend":

'export default DS.Model.extend'

The controller API docs say that "extend" creates a new subclass, is this not the same for Model?

Comment: You're confused about the difference between a _class_ or _type_ versus an _instance_ of that type-- a fundamental concept in object-oriented programming. When you extend a type, you create a blueprint for instances of that type: every model instance you create will have a `partner_id`. However `store.modelFor` does not return a model instance but rather the model class which you can use to `create` instances. More info in the guides: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/

Comment: Thanks. I have a reasonable understanding of OO from an earlier life of C++. I hadn't understood your previous explanation about `store.modelFor` returning the class rather than the instance. All makes perfect sense now, thanks for taking the time.